# Scanning a .ICS file and printing out specific lines to a .CSV. [JAVA]

Tags: java, excel, csv, icalendar

So I've been trying to make a program to scan in an excel file containing the contents of a .ics file.

This is what it looks like:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20160318T014953Z
**UID:bxxxxxxxxx@facebook.com**
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160506
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-APPLE-TRAVEL-ADVISORY-BEHAVIOR:AUTOMATIC
**SUMMARY:xxxxx xxxxxx's Birthday**
**DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160505**
DTSTAMP:20160323T112834Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
```

Now the file I have has exactly 100 of these 12 lines blocks of data.
I want to extract lines 3, 8 and 9 as strings so I can format them to my liking.

Ive been able to actually do all this, I'll spare the messy code... But it works.

However, I end up getting it written to the file like this (After my formatting):

```
www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx
www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx
www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
DATE:20160505
DATE:20160328
DATE:20160706
```

And in my excel file I want it to look like this: [Excel preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzcZ3.png)

This is probably a HUGE question and it's my first one, can't seem to get my head around it.
Still learning about Java every day. Not asking for a whole worked solution, but just how I could actually print to a .CSV file that way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[biweekly](https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly) might help.  It's a Java library that parses .ics files.